# Breaking out of loop (getting term in Fibonacci sequence)

Tags: ruby

Firstly I know there are alot of question using recursion on fibonacci, but my question is more specific on how I can implement my python code into my ruby code, and mine is more of just a looping through each element solution. For example here is my working python code to get the 1000th fibonacci element

```
from math import sqrt
primeCount = 1
num = 1
while(primeCount < 1000):
    num+=2
    for k in range(2,1+int(sqrt(num+1))):
        if num%k ==0:
            break
    else:
        primeCount+=1
print num
```

As you can see if we decide to `break` the `else` statement will never actually process even though its in a different block.

When I tried something similar in Ruby.

```
num = 1
primeCount = 1
while(primeCount < 1000)
    num+=2
    (1..Math.sqrt(num+1)).each do |k|
        if num%k == 0
            break;
        end
    end
    else
        primeCount+=1
    end
end
```

I get errors on where I should put the `end` keyword. Which makes sense. My question is, is there a way in which I can get my loop to skip `primeCount+=1`, when `num%k == 0` is true? I'm a bit confused, and have thought about this for a bit, and would like to implement a similar solution as to what I did in python.

Comment: Your `else..end` after `each do...end` doesn't make sense. Else from what? -- Oh right, your if. Your `else` is out of the scope of the block fed to `each`.

Comment: Exactly, but I don't want to put an else statement inside the loop either, because that would incorrectly increment `primeCount`, thats why i'm not really sure how to approach this.

Comment: But in the python version we don't have to worry about matching if and else in the same block

Comment: Which is why I don't understand the Python syntax/logic here. Maybe you can look for a more functional approach to the problem? I don't really understand the algorithm here, it's a little hard to grok from the code.

Comment: The first code basically just takes all odd numbers and mod's them with everything up to the square root. if that odd number mod 2  and mod all the way up until its square root is zero. It will just skip the else statement, and go to the next odd number. Its a bit funky, I do admit. Anyways no worries, thank you for trying :)

Comment: Using or recommending recursion to solve this problem is actually a common mistake. It's much better to iterate. You want to use recursion when you know there's a practical limit to how deeply you'll recurse. In these sorts of problems there is no limit.

Answer (score 2):

**Note 1**: The title mentions the Fibonacci sequence, but your code clearly generates primes, not Fibonacci numbers.

**Note 2**: It looks like you have a bug in your Ruby code, the range should start from 2, not from 1. After all, all numbers are divisible by 1. I fixed in in the code below.

In Ruby, `each` generally returns `self`, but if it's stopped by `break`, it returns `nil` (or the value specified as an argument to `break`). So you can do it like this:

```
num = primeCount = 1
while primeCount < 1000
  num+=2
  primeCount+=1 if (2..Math.sqrt(num+1)).each do |k|
    break if num%k == 0
  end
end
```

But if you want a real Ruby solution, here it goes:

```
require 'prime'
Prime.take 1000
```

Comment: For some reason i always get mixed up between fibonacci and primes lol i dont know why. Thanks alot this is a nice solution!

Comment: I just realized, in ruby we didn't have to typecast the Math.sqrt(num+1) into an integer, in python we did. Why is that?

Comment: See here: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Range.html Ranges in Ruby may  represent any set of values with a beginning and an end, so `('aa'..'zz')`, `(1.1..Math::PI)`, `(1/3r..2/3r)`, `(2..Float::INFINITY)` are all valid as ranges.